# Stochastic Hill Climbing

Tags: java, algorithm, simulated-annealing, stochastic, hill-climbing

I am trying to implement Stoachastic Hill Climbing in Java. I understand that this algorthim makes a new solution which is picked randomly and then accept the solution based on how bad/good it is. For example, if its very bad then it will have a small chance and if its slighlty bad then it will have more chances of being selected but I am not sure how I can implement this probability in java.

Whilst browing on Google, I came across this equation, where;

- f respresent the old fitness
- f' respresent the new fitness
- T is a parameter

[image]

I am not really sure how to interpret this equation.

Can someone please help me on how I can implement this in Java?

Comment: `Pr()` is probability. So `Pr(accept)` is the probability of accepting the solution for a given `f`, `f'`, and `T`.

Comment: In order to help you, we'll need more information about the code you've tried and why it doesn't suit your needs. An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am trying to understand this algorithm. I am not really sure how to implement it in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left hand side of the equation `p` will be a double between 0 and 1, inclusively. `oldFitness`, `newFitness` and `T` can also be doubles.

You will have something similar to this in your code:

```
double p = 1 / (1 + Math.exp((oldFitness - newFitness) / T));
if (Math.random() < p) {
    // accept the new solution
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good understating about the hill climbing algorithm in this book [Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/). This book also have a code repository, [here](https://code.google.com/p/aima-java/) you can found this.

And here is an implementation of [HillClimbing](http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/search/local/HillClimbingSearch.java) (HillclimbingSearch.java) in java. But this java file requires some other source file to be imported.
It's better If you have a look at the code repository. In this class you have a public method search() -

```
public List<Action> search(Problem p){}
```

From the method signature you can see this method require a `Problem` p and returns `List` of `Action`. To get these `Problem` and `Action` you have to use the [aima](https://code.google.com/p/aima-java/) framework.

You may found some more explanation about stochastic hill climbing [here](http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/constraints/stochastic.html)

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.